# Uploading files by dropzone.js give error, Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data;

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone to being able to upload multiple files to a Webservice, however I keep on getting error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data;      boundary=----------WmBuH1mgT5UyAi5sEK0qnm.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

this is my C# function

```
 public bool InvokeTest(byte[] binaryarray, string docname)
```

As I am trying to avoid Page_Load and try to make it work without a Form submit and only with a jQuery function as:

```
$('#dropzone').dropzone({
        url: '_upload/uploader.asmx/InvokeTest',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        maxFilesize: 1,
        paramName: 'photos',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        enqueueForUpload: false,
    });
```

my form submit looks simple:

```
<form id="Form1" action="_upload/uploader.asmx/InvokeTest" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" class="dropzone">
```

My questions:
Is it possible to use dropzone without "form" and post it direct through the jQuery and avoid my nasty error on the webservice....

Looking forward to any idea's and or suggestions,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropzone.js does work well in conjunction with a webservice & more specifically, it can be used in scenarios, where

- you are using a form to post to a WebServiceURL
- you are looking to upload multiple images

, which, judging by your question, you were originally looking to do.

Here is a detailed example of exactly such a scenario. Although in the example ServiceStack (rather than WCF) is being used as WebService:  [[ Uploading images using ServiceStack and Dropzone ]](http://www.buildclassifieds.com/2016/01/08/uploading-images-servicestack-and-dropzone/)

This suggests that your WebService c# function is not set up correctly to handle the post request.

Another important dropzone configuration is to use parallelUploads = 1. I have seen this being an issue if multiple uploads are looking to access the same memoryStream on the server-side implementation.

```
$('#dropzone').dropzone( {
            parallelUploads: 1,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: true
        });
```